# Electronで作ったアプリケーションをしばらく放置するとリロードされてしまう

Tags: javascript, electron

Electron（とVue）を使ってアプリケーションを作りました。
起動後、しばらく放置すると、画面が起動直後の状態に戻ってしまう現象に困っています。
たぶん、Chromiumの自動的なメモリ解放の仕組みか何か（[こういうの](https://aprico-media.com/posts/3107)）ではないか、と推測していますが、防ぐ手段は無いでしょうか。

なお、「画面が起動直後の状態に戻ってしまう現象」のその瞬間を目視確認できたことはありません。
ウィンドウを最小化してあって、ふと開いてみるとそうなっている、という状況です。

Electron 11.0
Windows 10

Comment: おそらく問題の現象を再現できる小さなサンプルプロジェクトを作って公開した方が良いと思われます。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ご自身がリンクを貼っているページにChromeの設定変更方法が記載されていますが、この方法は試したのでしょうか？それともその方法では問題があるのでしょうか？

Comment: Chromeの設定方法は確かに書いてありますが、Electron（で動くChromium）に対して設定する方法が分からず試せていません。

Comment: 比較的メジャーな現象であれば、質問の注目を集めればすぐ回答がつく（アプリとして致命的な現象なので、対策が普及しているはず）かなと思いましたが、どうもマイナーもしくは私のコード／環境固有の問題である可能性が高そうですね。再現条件（どのくらい待てば起きるのか等）もはっきりしないので、「再現可能な最小サンプル」も難しい・・・